# Accessing items in ObservableCollection bound to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection bound to a WPF DataGrid in which MyClass has a Boolean flag indicating if item has been seen or not.  If the item in the DataGrid is selected I want to set the MyClass.Seen property to true to indicate that it was viewed.  Initially, the SelectedIndex of the DataGrid matches to the index of the ObservableCollection but if I ever sort the DataGrid using any of the various columns that it displays, the SelectedIndex no longer matches with the ObservableCollection.

Up until now I have been looping thru the ObservableCollection comparing a value in MyClass to a column value of the DataGrid's SelectedIndex row to find a match.  Is there a better way to accomplish this where referencing the SelectedIndex of the DataGrid points me to the correct item in the ObservableCollection?

Comment: You should ask directed question about code you are having trouble with.  Be sure to show your code.

Comment: If someone needs to see the code, let me know and I will post it but @MSinger pointed me in the right direction w/ his almost immediate answer after my post w/o needing to see any............Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `SelectedIndex`, have you tried using `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue`? If the `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource` is set to your `ObservableCollection`, then those properties should point directly to the selected contained object.