# Accesing items in ObservableCollection bound to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I know this question is similar with [Accessing items in ObservableCollection bound to WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810285/accessing-items-in-observablecollection-bound-to-wpf-datagrid)

But the answers in this question doesn't helped me.

I've made a Class (DataItem.cs) where my ObservableCollection is.
And another class (SelectableViewModel.cs) where the Properties for the Columns are.

```
public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel> FirmCustomerItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel>();
}

public class SelectableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _columnName;

    public string ColumnName
    {
        get { return _columnName; }
        set
        {
            if (_columnName== value) return;
            _columnName= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

If I no want to access to the SelectedItem/Value/Items[0] I will get the following result:

"MyProject.SelectableViewModel".

This is the way how I want to access to the SelectedItem:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
switch (dataGrid.Name)
{
    case "FirmCustomerTableDataGrid":
        //var selected = dataGrid.SelectedValue;   // my First try
        //var selected = dataGrid.SelectedItem;    // my Second try
        var selected = dataGrid.SelectedItems[0] // my Third try
        MessageBox.Show(selected.ToString());
        break;
}
```

I the answers of the linked question at the top of my question is not working because I have a class for the column properties (SelectableViewModel).

But I don't know to solve this problem because I am not much familar with MVVM (rest of code is code-behind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the item to a `SelectableViewModel`:

```
var selected = dataGrid.SelectedItems[0] as SelectableViewModel;
if (selected != null)
    MessageBox.Show(selected.ColumnName);
```

Comment: If i use `SelectedItems[0]` i get out of index Error. And when i use `SelectedItem` I still get "MyProject.SelectableViewModel".
The Event where I call SelectedItem is called in the DataGrid because the Rows are dynamically added. Is this why that doesn't work ? And how to make it work?
Edit: I forgot to change the MessageBox too.

Thanks for you help. How is it called to cast items? (Word to google to better understand why I have to cast)

Comment: Edited my comment.

Comment: It's called type casting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions